# Unable to access sites during a SharePoint DR test

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Our company does not have hot DR site for our SharePoint environment.  So we are using the process to restore the data to our DR site:

1. Create all site collections in DR pointing to the same
   ContentDatabase name as it's counterpart in production (example if:
   http://prodsite/teams/team1 was pointing to PRD_ContentDB3 then we
   setup http://drsite/teams/team1 to point to PRD_ContentDB3 on the DR
   SQL Server).
2. Detatch and then delete the databases created in #1.
3. Restore production databases to the DR SQL Server.  Update all
   security on the databases to match production, but using the DR
   accounts.
4. Ran Powershell to re-attatch the database to SharePoint.

We are setup with CLAIMS authentication.

Once the restore was done, we could not connect to the sites that existed in production.  Every site returns an error: "**Sorry, something went wrong.  File not Found**.  If I create a new site collection in a new content database it works fine.  If I create a new site collection in a DB from prod it works, but anything that existed in prod will not work (including the root).

We have a DB alias setup that matches production (except points to the DR SQL server).  Has anyone else had this before?  Have I missed a step somewhere?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So actually I found out the databases were just fine.  The issue was the databases contained solutions that had not deployed properly.

I ran Test-SPContentDatabase on the databases being restored to the DR site.  It turns out that our custom code did not deploy properly.  I reattached the databases, redeployed our code and the DR site responds fine.